# How to change music output in moc, alsa

Tags: drivers, sound, output

I've been using moc for a while on a laptop and it is great, but then I wanted to plug in USB radio as an output, rhythmbox and other players detected new output device, but moc has output hardcoded in ~/.moc/config, where is stated:

```
# Sound driver - OSS, ALSA, JACK, SNDIO (on OpenBSD) or null (only for
# debugging).
# You can enter more than one driver as a colon-separated list.  The first
# working driver will be used.
SoundDriver             = JACK:ALSA:OSS

# Jack output settings.
JackOutLeft             = "alsa_pcm:playback_1"
JackOutRight            = "alsa_pcm:playback_2"

# OSS output device.
OSSDevice               = /dev/dsp

# OSS Mixer device.
OSSMixerDevice          = /dev/mixer

# OSS Mixer channel: pcm or master.
OSSMixerChannel         = pcm

# Second OSS Mixer channel: pcm or master.
OSSMixerChannel2        = master

# ALSA mixer device.
AlsaMixer               = PCM

# Second ALSA mixer device.
AlsaMixer2              = Master

# ALSA output device.
AlsaDevice              = default
```

And I have no idea, what to change. Some tutorial on devices and some additional help is needed.

I suppose, I have to change something in alsa, but neither in moc nor in alsamixer, I do not know how to check, where is my usb device and what to change.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using Jack audio server, but common Alsa:

Problem should probably be this line, which tells MOC to use default Alsa device (which is probably the internal sound card):

```
AlsaDevice              = default
```

Solution #1:
Change your Alsa default device every time you insert your USB audio stuff. That is nicely mentioned at Alsa FAQ page: http://alsa.opensrc.org/FAQ026
This can perhaps be scripted using udev (but that's another question I guess)

Solution #2:
Create second config file for MOC with different setting of `AlsaDevice` variable and everytime you run MOC, setup which config to use with `--config $FILE`. But I am not sure how to set properly `AlsaDevice` setting in MOC